# Converting from Web Forms to MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

Has anybody gone through the process of converting a real-world business application from ASP.NET web forms to MVC?  How painful was the transition?  Would you say that it was worth it, overall?

I am trying to figure out if it is worthwhile to take the time to convert an application over to MVC for increased performance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just an opinion but I would say don't do it. I've looked into this and have decided that we will use MVC for new apps and total rewrites because of the huge differences involved.

However I guess this really depends on what your asp.net pages looked like in the first place.

Comment: I think this is the route I will take.  Seems feasible to me.

Comment: I think the above comment is not a comprehensive answer to your open ended question, routing works fine in an existing Asp.Net application, so one approach could be to add any new pages as MVC to your forms project, then the task of converting existing pages can go onto your back-log as low priority.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently in the process of converting a couple of web form projects over to MVC. At first it was more to get familiar with the MVC, but now I actually really like how the model and the separation it provides.

The transition over has been a little hard in some area's in that there really isn't a lot of material other than some blogs, stackoverflow, and a couple of video casts. There are two books that are semi-available but, one is already kind of useless in that there have already been a number of changes to the framework that there are better ways in handling some things.

I also think you will have to really start to learn jQuery if you are already not familiar with it too. So for me - I feel like I am really learning two things as I've been doing this.

But worth it over all, I would say yes. And I think that converting a small project over is also really a great way to start.